# Delete multiple row if match whit string

Tags: python, pandas

I need help, I can't find a specific solution for my case, I have the following txt and I need to read it with Pandas and delete certain rows and then convert it to a csv:

```
Wed Oct 12 12:53:38.816 EDT                                                      #i need delete this row with the date
                                                                                 #i need delete this blank row 
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #i need delete this row whith the "-"
Lo0                up          up          Loopback0 interface configured by Netmiko
Lo55               up          up          
Lo100              up          up          ***MERGE LOOPBACK 100****
Lo111              up          up          Configured by NETCONF
Nu0                up          up          
Mg0/RP0/CPU0/0     up          up          DO NOT TOUCH THIS !
Gi0/0/0/0          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/1          admin-down  admin-down  test
Gi0/0/0/1.100      admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/2          admin-down  admin-down  Link to P2 configured by Netmiko
Gi0/0/0/3          up          up          Configured by Ansible !!!!!!!!
Gi0/0/0/4          up          up          Updated by Ansible using Jinja Template
Gi0/0/0/5          up          up          Configured by Ansible !!!!!!
Gi0/0/0/6          admin-down  admin-down  Updated by Ansible using Jinja Template
Gi0/0/0/6.11       admin-down  admin-down
```

and let it stay like this:

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
Lo0                up          up          Loopback0 interface configured by Netmiko
Lo55               up          up          
Lo100              up          up          ***MERGE LOOPBACK 100****
Lo111              up          up          Configured by NETCONF
Nu0                up          up          
Mg0/RP0/CPU0/0     up          up          DO NOT TOUCH THIS !
Gi0/0/0/0          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/1          admin-down  admin-down  test
Gi0/0/0/1.100      admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/0/2          admin-down  admin-down  Link to P2 configured by Netmiko
Gi0/0/0/3          up          up          Configured by Ansible !!!!!!!!
Gi0/0/0/4          up          up          Updated by Ansible using Jinja Template
Gi0/0/0/5          up          up          Configured by Ansible !!!!!!
Gi0/0/0/6          admin-down  admin-down  Updated by Ansible using Jinja Template
Gi0/0/0/6.11       admin-down  admin-down
```

try to start with this but it doesn't work and the regex is incomplete

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf("file.txt")

df = df[~df[0:].str.contains("Wed")]

print(df)
```

clearly I'm doing it wrong because it doesn't work, could you help me please?

**@MosGeo** your script works well but is so strict, i need to do a loop for because i need match this script with other match using if/else, i trying to do something like this(but is not working):

```
    with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    
with open("output2.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if re.match(r"([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)\-{5}\w", line):
            del line[line]
            f.write(line)
```

Final solution provided by **MosGeo**:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if not re.match(r"-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)", line):
        new_lines.append(line)

with open("output4.txt", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(new_lines)
```

Another possible solution I discovered:

```
regex = re.compile("-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)")
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open("output2.txt", "a") as fw:
    for line in lines:
        if re.match(regex, line):
           continue
        else:
            fw.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use pandas. Just read it as text and delete them. Here is an example to create the new file. Than just read it with pandas.

```py
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

del lines[3]
del lines[1]
del lines[0]

with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

You can also save on top of it if you want.

Edit:

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if not re.match(r"([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)\-{5}\w", line):
        new_lines .append(line)

with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(new_lines)
```

Comment: thanks MosGeo!! i edited my question for your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much MosGeo!! I modified some parameters to your script and it worked! Thanks a lot! I also managed to find another possible solution, I attach them to my question for the community, again thank you very much!

Comment: Great. Please marked it as the answer in the thread. Now that you get the hung of it, let me mention that you can actually pass the new_lines directly to pandas. You dont qctually need to save it in a file. That is why i seperated my new_lines creation and the writing phases.